# How to optimize multiple LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql

Some background:

We only have `SELECT` privilege for a MySQL database, and need to calculate how much money each user spent in the last 1, 2, ..., 45 days. The query is a huge collection of `LEFT JOIN`and I was tasked to optimize it. Note that to simplify the code I removed most of the `Round` and `LEFT JOIN` with comments.

The code:

```
SELECT m.username                                     AS 'Username', 

       # Actually we have 45 instead of 2 Round()
       Round(y2.spend, 2)                             AS '2', 
       Round(y1.spend, 2)                             AS '1' 
FROM   fund_m AS fm 
       LEFT JOIN member AS m 
              ON fm.user_id = m.id 
       LEFT JOIN employee AS e 
              ON m.account_manager = e.id

       # Again we have 45 instead of 2 LEFT JOIN following
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT fm.user_id                    AS id, 
                         Sum(fm.amount_changed) *- 1 AS 'spend' 
                  FROM   fund_m AS fm 
                  WHERE  fm.arrival_date = Subdate(CURRENT_DATE, 1) 
                         AND fm.type = 'impressions' 
                  GROUP  BY fm.user_id) AS y1 
              ON fm.user_id = y1.id 

       LEFT JOIN (SELECT fm.user_id                    AS id, 
                         Sum(fm.amount_changed) *- 1 AS 'spend' 
                  FROM   fund_m AS fm 
                  WHERE  fm.arrival_date = Subdate(CURRENT_DATE, 2) 
                         AND fm.type = 'impressions' 
                  GROUP  BY fm.user_id) AS y2 
              ON fm.user_id = y2.id 

WHERE  fm.arrival_date BETWEEN Subdate(CURRENT_DATE, 45) AND Subdate( 
                               CURRENT_DATE, 1) 
       AND fm.type = 'impressions' 
GROUP  BY m.username;
```

The structure of table `fm` is as following:

Each user has an `user_id` and `arrival_date` column, so the code checks if the arrival date is 1, 2, ... , 45 days before `CURRENT_DATE` and then `Sum` the `amount_charged` based on that. The script will also show the summation as columns. So there will be 45 columns of summation result for each `user_id`.

This is my first day with SQL, after some research I came to the conclusion:

1) It contains 45 `Round()` and `LEFT JOIN`, and is screaming for a LOOP or something. However AFAIK I can only use `LOOP` in a stored procedure, which I cannot do so. The next thought is to see if I can create a temp table to hold a sequence from 1~45. However I searched on SO for a while and could not pinpoint the post that really helps.

2) Is it possible to generate 45 columns without using `LEFT JOIN`? Because I know that `LEFT JOIN` takes a lot of resource, and 45 (actually 47) `LEFT JOIN` doesn't seem to be a good idea (45 of them are self `LEFT JOIN`). But I have no idea how to optimize this.

**Updated**
A thought, sorry I'm out of workspace so can't test. Just read about `SELECT` `CASE` `WHEN` `ELSE` `END`. So maybe I can use `CASE` to filter the date (e.g. `CASE` `WHEN` the difference between now and `arrival_date` is 1, 2, ..., 45 days). But still I need to generate 45 columns...

Comment: You can also use the IF function since you basically just have two options. Case is good when you have multiple options. ```SUM(IF(SubDate(CURRENT_DATE,1) = arrival_date,spend,0))```. Change the "1" to the number of days in the past (ie. 1-45)

Comment: Also, in the when for the query, limit the rows to the past 45 days.

Comment: @SloanThrasher Thanks will try it out when I get the remote server running. We do have a `WHERE` to limit the query to 45 days, I'll add it in the code.

Comment: @SloanThrasher Actually it's in the code, `WHERE fm.arrival_date BETWEEN Subdate(CURRENT_DATE, 45) AND Subdate(CURRENT_DATE, 1)`, should be good?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more-simplified version.  Pre-aggregate based on qualified date and impression type records per user.  From that,

```
select
      m.username AS 'Username',
      SUM( if( PQ.Days = 1, PQ.Spend, 0 )) as `1`,
      SUM( if( PQ.Days = 2, PQ.Spend, 0 )) as `2`,
      SUM( if( PQ.Days = 3, PQ.Spend, 0 )) as `3`,
      SUM( if( PQ.Days = 44, PQ.Spend, 0 )) as `44`,
      SUM( if( PQ.Days = 45, PQ.Spend, 0 )) as `45`,
   from
      ( select
              fm.user_id,
              datediff( current_date, fm.arrival_date ) as Days,
              Round( Sum(fm.amount_changed) * -1, 2 ) AS 'spend' 
           from
              fund_m AS fm 
           where
                  fm.arrival_date >= Date_Sub( Current_Date, interval 45 day )
              AND fm.type = 'impressions' 
           group by
              fm.user_id,
              datediff( current_date, fm.arrival_date )) PQ
         LEFT JOIN member AS m 
            ON PQ.user_id = m.id
            LEFT JOIN employee AS e
               ON m.account_manager = e.id
   group by
      m.username
```

If you look at the inner PQ (Pre-Query), I am applying all 45 days (where clause), and grouping by user and Days, I have the IF() computed days going back (0-45 days).  At the end of this query, you would have AT MOST, 1 record per person per day, so the outer query joining can get rest of the data from the join.

The bigger difference here is it is not throwing 45 date comparisons for every row, just one to determine the # days from current.  Now you have a finite set much smaller from the pre-aggregation to do a simple check on days to get that day's total.

Group as you had is by user, but you are then joining to the employee table on the account manager value.  Did you intend to get the totals based on account MANAGER's name?  If not, there is no need to even join to the employee table unless you have some other fields you are not grabbing per this sample.

Comment: Thank you! As a newbie, the idea of "Pre-Query" is very interesting, and makes sense. I'll test the script to see how it works. May I ask you one more thing? You mentioned "have a finite set much smaller", I figured that this is probably one of the pillars to optimize a query, how should I take notice of this while learning SQL? For now I only know a few commands and I'd rather get things done slowly than not getting anything, but I'm pretty sure optimization is going to be super important in the near future.

Comment: About the last paragraph: No I don't need to group the totals by account_manager, it's by user. The second 'LEFT JOIN', as I understand, is to fetch the users that were acquired by account managers only. I'll check the database to see if this is needed.

Comment: @NicholasHumphrey, sorry no prior response.  Everyone has their style of writing queries.  Instead of just GIVING an answer, I typically like to educate WHY a certain approach.  There are many great minds out here, but if you click on my link, answers you can look and review as you need.  You can do the same for others who post too.  There are resources all over the net, but sometimes generics don't help your situation.  Learning how I attack a query might help.  Also always table.column (or alias.column) and ensure joins left-to-right for readability and consistency.  Per so many I do too.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is first group and pivot them into 45 columns using MAX on fund_m table grouped by user_id and then join them to member. This will avoid multiple joins to same table.

Ex:

```
SELECT m.username, ROUND('spend1',2) '1', ROUND('spend2',2) '2', .... ROUND('spend45',2) '45'
FROM member AS m
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT fm.user_id AS id,  
    SUM(CASE WHEN fm.arrival_date = Subdate(CURRENT_DATE, 1)  
         THEN fm.amount_changed *- 1 END) AS 'spend1',
    SUM(CASE WHEN fm.arrival_date = Subdate(CURRENT_DATE, 2)  
         THEN fm.amount_changed *- 1 END) AS 'spend2',
    ....,
    SUM(CASE WHEN fm.arrival_date = Subdate(CURRENT_DATE, 44)  
         THEN fm.amount_changed *- 1 END) AS 'spend44',
    SUM(CASE WHEN fm.arrival_date = Subdate(CURRENT_DATE, 45)  
         THEN fm.amount_changed *- 1 END) AS 'spend45'
    FROM  fund_m AS fm 
    WHERE fm.arrival_date BETWEEN Subdate(CURRENT_DATE, 45) AND Subdate(CURRENT_DATE, 1) 
    AND fm.type = 'impressions' 
    GROUP BY fm.user_id 
) X ON fm.user_id = X.id
LEFT JOIN employee AS e ON m.account_manager = e.id
```

Answer (score 1):

This should provide the results you're looking for:

```
SELECT 
    m.username,
    Round(SUM(IF(SubDate(CURRENT_DATE,1) = fm.arrival_date,fm.amount_changed * -1,0)),2) as `1`,
    Round(SUM(IF(SubDate(CURRENT_DATE,2) = fm.arrival_date,fm.amount_changed * -1,0)),2) as `2`,
    Round(SUM(IF(SubDate(CURRENT_DATE,3) = fm.arrival_date,fm.amount_changed * -1,0)),2) as `3`,
    Round(SUM(IF(SubDate(CURRENT_DATE,4) = fm.arrival_date,fm.amount_changed * -1,0)),2) as `4`,
    Round(SUM(IF(SubDate(CURRENT_DATE,5) = fm.arrival_date,fm.amount_changed * -1,0)),2) as `5`,
    Round(SUM(IF(SubDate(CURRENT_DATE,6) = fm.arrival_date,fm.amount_changed * -1,0)),2) as `6`,
    Round(SUM(IF(SubDate(CURRENT_DATE,7) = fm.arrival_date,fm.amount_changed * -1,0)),2) as `7`,
    Round(SUM(IF(SubDate(CURRENT_DATE,8) = fm.arrival_date,fm.amount_changed * -1,0)),2) as `8`,
    Round(SUM(IF(SubDate(CURRENT_DATE,9) = fm.arrival_date,fm.amount_changed * -1,0)),2) as `9`,
    Round(SUM(IF(SubDate(CURRENT_DATE,10) = fm.arrival_date,fm.amount_changed * -1,0)),2) as `10`,
    Round(SUM(IF(SubDate(CURRENT_DATE,11) = fm.arrival_date,fm.amount_changed * -1,0)),2) as `11`,
    Round(SUM(IF(SubDate(CURRENT_DATE,12) = fm.arrival_date,fm.amount_changed * -1,0)),2) as `12`,
    Round(SUM(IF(SubDate(CURRENT_DATE,13) = fm.arrival_date,fm.amount_changed * -1,0)),2) as `13`,
    Round(SUM(IF(SubDate(CURRENT_DATE,14) = fm.arrival_date,fm.amount_changed * -1,0)),2) as `14`,
    Round(SUM(IF(SubDate(CURRENT_DATE,15) = fm.arrival_date,fm.amount_changed * -1,0)),2) as `15`,
    Round(SUM(IF(SubDate(CURRENT_DATE,16) = fm.arrival_date,fm.amount_changed * -1,0)),2) as `16`,
    Round(SUM(IF(SubDate(CURRENT_DATE,17) = fm.arrival_date,fm.amount_changed * -1,0)),2) as `17`,
    Round(SUM(IF(SubDate(CURRENT_DATE,18) = fm.arrival_date,fm.amount_changed * -1,0)),2) as `18`,
    Round(SUM(IF(SubDate(CURRENT_DATE,19) = fm.arrival_date,fm.amount_changed * -1,0)),2) as `19`,
    Round(SUM(IF(SubDate(CURRENT_DATE,20) = fm.arrival_date,fm.amount_changed * -1,0)),2) as `20`,
    Round(SUM(IF(SubDate(CURRENT_DATE,21) = fm.arrival_date,fm.amount_changed * -1,0)),2) as `21`,
    Round(SUM(IF(SubDate(CURRENT_DATE,22) = fm.arrival_date,fm.amount_changed * -1,0)),2) as `22`,
    Round(SUM(IF(SubDate(CURRENT_DATE,23) = fm.arrival_date,fm.amount_changed * -1,0)),2) as `23`,
    Round(SUM(IF(SubDate(CURRENT_DATE,24) = fm.arrival_date,fm.amount_changed * -1,0)),2) as `24`,
    Round(SUM(IF(SubDate(CURRENT_DATE,25) = fm.arrival_date,fm.amount_changed * -1,0)),2) as `25`,
    Round(SUM(IF(SubDate(CURRENT_DATE,26) = fm.arrival_date,fm.amount_changed * -1,0)),2) as `26`,
    Round(SUM(IF(SubDate(CURRENT_DATE,27) = fm.arrival_date,fm.amount_changed * -1,0)),2) as `27`,
    Round(SUM(IF(SubDate(CURRENT_DATE,28) = fm.arrival_date,fm.amount_changed * -1,0)),2) as `28`,
    Round(SUM(IF(SubDate(CURRENT_DATE,29) = fm.arrival_date,fm.amount_changed * -1,0)),2) as `29`,
    Round(SUM(IF(SubDate(CURRENT_DATE,30) = fm.arrival_date,fm.amount_changed * -1,0)),2) as `30`,
    Round(SUM(IF(SubDate(CURRENT_DATE,31) = fm.arrival_date,fm.amount_changed * -1,0)),2) as `31`,
    Round(SUM(IF(SubDate(CURRENT_DATE,32) = fm.arrival_date,fm.amount_changed * -1,0)),2) as `32`,
    Round(SUM(IF(SubDate(CURRENT_DATE,33) = fm.arrival_date,fm.amount_changed * -1,0)),2) as `33`,
    Round(SUM(IF(SubDate(CURRENT_DATE,34) = fm.arrival_date,fm.amount_changed * -1,0)),2) as `34`,
    Round(SUM(IF(SubDate(CURRENT_DATE,35) = fm.arrival_date,fm.amount_changed * -1,0)),2) as `35`,
    Round(SUM(IF(SubDate(CURRENT_DATE,36) = fm.arrival_date,fm.amount_changed * -1,0)),2) as `36`,
    Round(SUM(IF(SubDate(CURRENT_DATE,37) = fm.arrival_date,fm.amount_changed * -1,0)),2) as `37`,
    Round(SUM(IF(SubDate(CURRENT_DATE,38) = fm.arrival_date,fm.amount_changed * -1,0)),2) as `38`,
    Round(SUM(IF(SubDate(CURRENT_DATE,39) = fm.arrival_date,fm.amount_changed * -1,0)),2) as `39`,
    Round(SUM(IF(SubDate(CURRENT_DATE,40) = fm.arrival_date,fm.amount_changed * -1,0)),2) as `40`,
    Round(SUM(IF(SubDate(CURRENT_DATE,41) = fm.arrival_date,fm.amount_changed * -1,0)),2) as `41`,
    Round(SUM(IF(SubDate(CURRENT_DATE,42) = fm.arrival_date,fm.amount_changed * -1,0)),2) as `42`,
    Round(SUM(IF(SubDate(CURRENT_DATE,43) = fm.arrival_date,fm.amount_changed * -1,0)),2) as `43`,
    Round(SUM(IF(SubDate(CURRENT_DATE,44) = fm.arrival_date,fm.amount_changed * -1,0)),2) as `44`,
    Round(SUM(IF(SubDate(CURRENT_DATE,45) = fm.arrival_date,fm.amount_changed * -1,0)),2) as `45`
FROM fund_m AS fm 
LEFT JOIN member AS m 
    ON fm.user_id = m.id 
LEFT JOIN employee AS e 
    ON m.account_manager = e.id
WHERE fm.arrival_date BETWEEN SubDate(CURRENT_DATE,45) AND CURRENT_DATE
    AND fm.type = 'impressions'
GROUP BY m.username
ORDER BY m.username;
```

Comment: this query is incomplete and doesn't match OPs structure, the username is coming from a different table. You can update this to join to member table and look for impression type rows only.

Comment: @rs. I've updated the query. Thanks for the heads up.